# moment js: get days between period

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have a period of 6 days between 2 iso strings:

```
const period = {
start: "2020-07-19T22:00:00.000Z",
end: "2020-07-25T22:00:00.000Z"
}
```

I'd like to have the 6 different days of the week included into this period like

```
 [
'monday',
'tuesday',
'wednesday',
 etc
]
```

So far this is what I came up with:

```
const days = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
      const day = moment(this.period.start).add(i, 'days');
      days.push(moment(day).day());
    }
```

Is there a simple/elegant way to do this with moment.js?

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: You can get the difference in days (via `.diff()`) and then iterate from your start date. There does not appear to be a Moment API to do what you want.

Comment: There is no ***elegant*** way to do this with Moment.js per se, you still need a loop. And the solution you tried so far has two main problems, it adds an increasing number of days on each iteration, and you probably need `.format('dddd')` instead of `.day()`.

Answer (score 2):

```js
        var period = {
            start: "2020-07-19T22:00:00.000Z",
            end: "2020-07-25T22:00:00.000Z"
        }
        var i = 0;
        var dates = [];
        while (i < moment(period.end).diff(period.start, 'days')) {

            var date = moment(period.start).add(i, 'days').format('dddd');
            dates.push(date);
            i++;
        }
        document.getElementById('div').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(dates);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.0/moment.min.js"></script>
 <div id="div"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can possibly use this approach that will create an array from the difference between the two dates in days, then a `.map()` call on it where you can take advantage of the index to add days to the start date and get the right format.

```js
const period = {
    start: "2020-07-19T22:00:00.000Z",
    end: "2020-07-25T22:00:00.000Z"
};
const startDate = moment(period.start);
const endDate = moment(period.end);
const days = new Array(endDate.diff(startDate, 'days')).fill(null)
             .map((v, index) => (
                 startDate.clone().add(index, 'days').format('dddd')
             ));
             
console.log(days);
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
```